# ¿Cómo eliminar un valor de una columna csv pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo un archivo csv (una columna por ejemplo es enero [545, 334, -5747, ups, 5885])(hay columnas de enero a diciembre y algunas columnas son del mismo tipo(int) pero algunos datos de alguna columna son de tipo string, puestos de forma intencionada))  y quiero sumar todos los números de una columna, pero un valor de esa columna es una palabra, como puedo eliminar esa palabra de la columna o que el programa convierta esa palabra a 0 para poder sumar todos los valores, ya que cuando hago un type(de esa columna), python entiende que todos los datos de la columna son de tipo string y no los puedo sumar. He intentado recorrer la columna con un bucle for y compruebe que todos los datos son números y cuando encuentre un valor que no es un numero lo elimine de la columna o lo convierta en 0, también he intentado con el método to_numeric() ó astype() pero no doy con la solución. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Aplicando `pd.to_numeric` a la columna y forzando los errores a ser sustituidos por NaN te debería funcionar. Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Bienvenido Caleb Zamalloa a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.